# Typecast to integer or get integer division in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I'm currently working on a script that calculates stuff based on predefined levels.
So I'm tacking the price and divide it by a configurable value and I want to get the integer value for this division.
In C-code it would look like this:

```
newValue = (int)( close / divValue )
```

In Pinescript it will just make a typecast to float and the modulo-operator will just give me the remains of the division.
Is there some way to make a typecast from float to integer or something like a reverse modulo?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [int()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_int) function for that.
Here's an example.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)

var float   myClose     = 130.98
var int     divValue    = 3

var int     newValue    = na
var float   remainder   = na

newValue    := int(myClose / divValue)
remainder   := myClose % divValue

plotchar(newValue,  "newValue",  "")
plotchar(remainder, "remainder", "")
```